# yii2 how can you create a signup widget so in any view you can create user

Tags: php, yii2

Using yii2 I have the default signup page however I'd like to render the signup form within another view this will be usefully not just for signup form but if you were wanting to render newsletter signup form in various places within an app.

So i know how to render the form whether is the correct way or not I am not 100% sure.

So I want to know how can I use the action that the signup page does which is in the sitecontroller file.

Report Controller

```
namespace frontend\controllers;

use frontend\models\SignupForm;
use frontend\models\Report;
...
public function actionIndex()
{

    $published = true;

    $signupModel = new SignupForm();

    $searchModel = new ReportSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $published);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'signupModel' => $signupModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
...
```

In my report index view I have the below code which renders the form but doesn't register etc the page just refreshed (VIEW).

```
<?= \Yii::$app->view->renderFile('@app/views/site/signup.php', ['model' => $signupModel]); ?>
```

Comment: Such functionality is covered by widgets, check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19049682/133408 (its for Yii 1, but in 2 you should use similar approach)

Comment: Checkout widgets, consider them reusable pieces of code that can be used anywhere. You should not try to call another controller's action to get some info there that is now how MVC should work.

Comment: @MihaiP. I managed to create signup form widget however kept getting an error as it was saying $model not defined. Do I extend the current/default signup controller or create a new controller with the same/similar code? Any guides on creating form widgets with actions etc?

Comment: Widgets do not have actions, you still need to post your data to a controller. As a rule, whatever comes in / goes out has to come through a controller. I personally would post to a controller, the controller returns json  data and errors that I can use in the widget. Then you can use the widget anywhere. I use this to have both a login full page and a popup where I can login. They both work through the same widget that renders the form. Both places post to the same controller and the controller returns json data with errors or success.

Comment: @MihaiP. Any chance you could possibly post the example or send me it in another way as I think I need a working example so I can look through the code workout what does what etc as I am struggling to jump from fairly static widgets to widgets that work with form etc.

Comment: I do not have a public example sorry, only on private repositories. But it is not that complicated, put the active form inside the widget, post the form result to the controller.